# How can I get the input label to fade when I focus or select the input & can I also get the label to be inside the input?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to do 2 things here: 
1) I want the label to change to a lighter shade of grey when the input is selected.  However, I can't get all the labels to change color.

2) I want to put the label inside the input. However, I am more concerned about the first than the second, as by implementing the second one would cancel out the first one I believe. But it would be nice to know how to position a label inside an input.

I am using the CSS input:focus ~ label method however, this just selects the labels AFTER the input and I have the label before the input therefore the first label is not working for the fade. 
How can I get all the labels to change color when an input is selected? I know I need to move the label after the input however, if I do that the label will show up underneath the input which is not where it is supposed to go.
I have tried position: absolute on the label but it just bunches them together, so I am not sure how to move them individually.

Here is the link to my codepen, I have two contact forms, one separated with divs the other is not.

https://codepen.io/RJorns/pen/MdmoRp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">


<div class="contact-wrapper">
    <div class="contact-title"><h1>Contact</h1></div>
    <form class="contact-form ui equal width form">
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <label class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input class="form-input" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <label class="form-label">Message</label>
      <div class="field">
        <textarea rows="4" id="message" type="text" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <button id="submit" class="ui grey button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

<div class="contact-wrapper">
    <div class="contact-title"><h1>Contact</h1></div>
    <form class="contact-form ui equal width form">
        <label class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input class="form-input" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input class="form-input" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
      <label class="form-label">Message</label>
      <div class="field">
        <textarea rows="4" id="message" type="text" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <button id="submit" class="ui grey button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>




* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Contact */

    .contact-wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 75%;
    }

    .contact-title {
      margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    .contact-form {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
    }

    input {
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px -1px rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
    }

    .form-label {
      display: flex;
      color: #515151;
    }

    input:focus ~ label {
      color: #a0a0a0;
    }

    button {
      margin-top: 5em;
    }
```

I want the all the labels to show a lighter grey when it is focused.
I want to use CSS only but if I have to use JS that is fine.

Comment: "I want to put the label inside the input" whats that mean?

Comment: In other words instead of a placeholder it would be nice to put the <label>Name</label> inside of the <input> tag. However, that is secondary to what I really need, as if I had the label inside the input it would have to disappear so the user can type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved the `label` after the input for label section from css and used the column reverse to move the label on top. Also added the transition on input focus. I hope this will work. Comment for more info.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: center;
}


/* Contact */

.contact-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 75%;
}

.contact-title {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.contact-form {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

input {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px -1px rgba(77, 77, 77, 1);
}

.form-label {
    display: flex;
    color: #515151;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

input:focus ~ label {
    color: #a0a0a0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.form-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

button {
    margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">

<div class="contact-wrapper">
    <div class="contact-title">
        <h1>Contact</h1></div>
    <form class="contact-form ui equal width form">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <input class="form-input" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" required>
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <input class="form-input" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
            <label class="form-label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <label class="form-label">Message</label>
        <div class="field">
            <textarea rows="4" id="message" type="text" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="submit" class="ui grey button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="contact-wrapper">
    <div class="contact-title">
        <h1>Contact</h1></div>
    <form class="contact-form ui equal width form">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <input class="form-input" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" required>
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <input class="form-input" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
            <label class="form-label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <label class="form-label">Message</label>
        <div class="field">
            <textarea rows="4" id="message" type="text" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="submit" class="ui grey button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```